# How to test spring boot security ssl controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

We have an application which is using spring-boot-security and configured to use ssl.

below is my security configuration

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access?error");
        // @formatter:on
    }

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin")
            .roles("ADMIN", "USER", "ACTUATOR").and().withUser("user")
            .password("user").roles("USER");
}
```

We have a method level security controller with below code

```
@GetMapping("/")
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public String home(Map<String, Object> model)
{
    model.put("message", "Hello World");
    model.put("title", "Hello Home");
    model.put("date", new Date());
    return "home";
}
```

Now we want to write Junit case for the controller using the `@WebMvcTest` Annotation so first I want to login and then check for mapping `/`

I have written JUNIT test case as

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HomeController.class, secure = true)
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    // @WithMockUser(authorities = "ADMIN")
    public void testHome() throws Exception
    {
        /*
         * TestSecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( new
         * UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "admin", AuthorityUtils
         * .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN")));
         */
        this.mvc.perform(formLogin("/login").user("u", "admin").password("p", "admin"))
                /*
                 * get("/").with(user("admin").password("pass").roles("USER",
                 * "ADMIN")) .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                 */
                .andExpect(authenticated()).andDo(print());
    }

}
```

How to make sure that my JUNIT is working as expected.  below is my print() method log. I see that port is missing, how to set this?

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /login
       Parameters = {u=[admin], p=[admin], _csrf=[3f104e63-4a77-487c-9d1c-8b7cf2c2cead]}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Location=[https://localhost/login]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = https://localhost/login
          Cookies = []
```

Code base of the project can be found in [github](https://github.com/rajadilipkolli/jshop-ecommerce)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should probably set the `defaultSuccessUrl()` when configuring the form-based login (e.g., by setting it to "/"). Then the user will get redirected after a successful login attempt.

Once you've configured that, it will be easier to test your use case.

You can first test that a successful login redirects to the homepage ("/") by using `.andExpect(redirectedUrl("/"))`. That should be in one test method.

In a second test method annotated with `@WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")` you can then verify that an *ADMIN* is allowed to access the homepage ("/").

Regarding the port number, if you determine you really need to set a custom port, you should be able to register a custom [SpringBootMockMvcBuilderCustomizer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/SpringBootMockMvcBuilderCustomizer.html) as a bean in the `ApplicationContext` and use it to set the default request that can specify your custom port.

Regards,

Sam